# Как найти системные переменные в Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, java

Не могу найти системные переменные `CLASSPATH` и `JAVA_HOME` в Windows 7.
Разуйте, пожалуйста, мне глаза или, в крайнем случае, подскажите, где искать.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "найти"? Они видны в соответствующем диалоговом окне? echp %JAVA_HOME% ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тебе необходимо самому их прописать: зайди - 
Компьютер-Свойства-Изменить параметры-Вкладка - дополнительно-Переменные среды - там их и создай и передай им правильные параметры (у меня JAVA_HOME значение C:Program FilesJavajdk1.6.0_26)

Comment: Спасиба :)

Comment: Как странно.. по идее после установки Java на винде эти переменные обычно выставлены как надо...

Comment: точно-точно. нифига не прописывается при установке.

Comment: то прописывается, то не прописывается. когда как.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Как найти системные переменные?

Встроенные во все версии Windows средства работы с пользовательскими/системными переменными достаточно неудобны, на Super User [**рекомендуют**](https://superuser.com/a/297950/572069) воспользоваться бесплатным GUI-приложением Rapid Environment Editor (REE).

Чтобы перейти к работе с системными/пользовательскими переменными, не нужно каждый раз совершать множество кликов: достаточно только запустить исполняемый файл программы → и переменные должны отобразиться в списке. Синим прямоугольником выделены значения `CLASSPATH` и `JAVA_HOME` для меня.

[image: Java переменные]

---

---

### 2. Прочие преимущества Rapid Environment Editor

1. Бэкап переменных в 2 клика — `File` → `Backup`.
2. Выделение красным переменных, путь к которым указан некорректно.

[image: Некорректные пути]

3. Алфавитная сортировка, облегчающая визуальный поиск.
4. Показываются и переменные, доступные только для чтения, но не модификации.