# Что такое pull request?

Tags: git, github

Что такое "пул реквест" (pull request), который на GitHub, и как его применить?

Comment: [Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) в частности. [Помощь по github](https://help.github.com/) в целом

Comment: [Pull request'ы на GitHub или Как мне внести изменения в чужой проект](http://habrahabr.ru/post/125999/).  [Кнопка слияния на GitHub (Merge)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/118124/)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Зачем нужен pull request, если есть push?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505731/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-pull-request-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-push)

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, на официальном сайте GitHub — который, на мой взгляд, является наиболее авторитетным источником насчёт именования термина, — термин «pull request» пишется строчными буквами, примеры: [**About pull requests**](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/), [**Merging a pull request**](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/), [**Reverting a pull request**](https://help.github.com/articles/reverting-a-pull-request/). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных он там по-разному пишется. Перейдите по той ссылке, которую вы приводили первый раз и посмотрите в самый низ

Comment: @СашаЧерных в любом случае, зачем вы точку с запятой ставите?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, перешёл по ссылкам. Единственное, в первой ссылке внизу в разделе «Further reading» встречаются заглавные буквы в ссылках. Но если кликнуть по ним, в заголовках открывшихся статей будут строчные буквы. Преимущество строчных над заглавными большое. Спасибо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, [**§ 131.2**](http://www.rusyaz.ru/pr/ptz.html). Спасибо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov pull request - не имя собственное. С заглавных букв его стоит писать только в заголовках на англоязычных сайтах. На ruSO вариант "Что Такое Pull Request" будет выглядеть странно.

Comment: 50 плюсов у (даже до сих пор открытого!) вопроса, ответ на который лежит в официальной справке, в википедии, в гугле, где угодно. Я фигею с этого комьюнити.

Answer (score 111):

Смотрим за руками.

1. Крутой программер создал репозиторий.
2. Вы сделали форк его репозитория (т.е. скопировали к себе).
3. Вы сделали какие-то крутые изменения в своём репозитории.

Теперь если вы хотите, чтобы крутой дядя внёс ваши крутые изменения в свой крутой код. И вы просите, чтобы он взял ваши изменения, т.е. сделал `git pull`. Это и называется *pull request*

Comment: А как теперь этот пулл реквест применить к своему репозиторию?))

Comment: Нажать "Accept Pull Request", не?

Comment: Что значит применить? Вы просите кого то (нажав кнопку на гитхабе) влить ВАШИ изменения в ЕГО репозиторий. Влить или не вливать - его дело.

Comment: Почему «крутой», «крутые»? Я мелочи, в основном, делаю. Исправляю [**небольшие баги**](https://github.com/Doi9t/SortBy/pull/15#issuecomment-250030492), изменяю [**формат даты**](https://github.com/jasongardnerlv/jernl/pull/2), добавляю [**улучшения в юзабилити**](https://github.com/kiliwalk/Sublime_ConEmuOpen/pull/3) и т. д. Самое смешное: пофиксишь опечатку — GitHub тебя уже в контрибуторы зачисляет. Спасибо.

Comment: `git pull` тут ни при чём. При принятии реквеста `git merge` делается.

Comment: @NickVolynkin вообще-то, pull = fetch + merge. Как вы представляете merge чужих изменений без предварительного fetch?

Comment: @PavelMayorov они разнесены во времени. Fetch делается при открытии реквеста, а merge – при закрытии. Если владелец репозитория будет мержить руками, а не через веб-интерфейс, то ему нужно будет сделать `git fetch; git merge origin/feature; git push`. Не могу сходу придумать, как принять мерж-реквест с мержем через git pull.

Comment: @NickVolynkin `git pull origin забыл/какая/ветка/для/PR`

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну да, так можно, но я не знаю никого, кто именно так принимает пулл-реквесты. Вы так делаете?

Comment: @NickVolynkin не важно делает так кто или нет. Операции fetch и merge вместе называются pull.

Answer (score 48):

К вышесказанному можно добавить следующее. Далеко не все пулл-реквесты принимаются разработчиками. Тут нужно соблюсти ряд правил:

1. Пулл-реквест (ПР) должен быть хорошо оформлен и содержать
   исчерпывающее описание.
2. Обычное правило, один баг - один ПР, одна фича - один ПР. Не нужно
   пытаться впихнуть сразу кучу всего.
3. Очень важно соблюдать Code Style того проекта, для которого вы
   делаете ПР. Пусть даже он кажется вам противоестественным (например
   вы всегда делаете отступы в виде 4 пробелов, а в проекте табы).

Не нужно бояться делать ПР-ы, ведь помочь можно даже в мелочи. Например вы заметили ошибку перевода в readme файле или вам кажется что какое-то описание фичи можно более понятно перефразировать.

На гитхабе миллионы проектов, живущие исключительно на энтузиазме создателей, хорошие ПР-ы очень хорошо подстегивают этот энтузиазм)

Answer (score 22):

Пулл Реквест это что-то типа сообщения автору оригинального репозитория со смыслом "эй, я тут сделал крутую штуку, рекомендую добавить ее в такую-то ветку". Автор оригинальной репы смотрит на ваши "крутые штуки" и решает - сделать пулл или не сделать, вмерджить в ветку или нет.

еще добавки к вышесказанному: возможный (я им пользуюсь) механизм работы с репами/pr:

форкаете репозиторий, например https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11

после этого

`git clone https://github.com/ваш_юзернейм/sqlpp11.git`

`cd sqlpp11`

`git remote add upstream https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11.git` (т.е. мы добавляем псевдоним upstream для оригинального репозитория, мы не можем добавлять в него изменения, но можем их получать)

`git checkout -b названиеБранча` (ветки)

теперь вы правите файлы в вашем origin, в вашей ветке, пушите их в свой форк гитхаба (origin), откуда и делаете pull-request

при этом вы можете сделать git merge/pull/fetch upstream  с оригинального репозитория (upstream)

если в upstream настроена интеграция типа travis-ci (как в моем примере), лучше не делать пулл-реквесты, пока не настроите travis-ci  для своего репозитория и ваши билды не будут работать правильно (чтобы не мучать мэйнтейнера upstream бессмысленными сообщениями о неудачных сборках в пулл-реквесте)

общий алгоритм работы примерно такой:
`git fetch; git merge upstream/ветка;` (master/debug/и т.д.)
сделали изменения: `git push`, изменения улетают в ваш форк на гитахабе. Eсли настроен travis, проходят тесты/сборки, когда вы уверены в качестве коммита, делаете pull request из вашего форка. Если PR приняли, делаете, допустим, `git checkout master; git fetch; git merge upstream/ветка`, чтобы ваш форк оставался консистентным с оригиналом.

вмердженные в upstream (оригиальный репозиторй)  и в ваш origin/master (ваш форк на гитхабе, в данном случае) ветки можно удалять - руками или с помощью, например, https://github.com/arc90/git-sweep

Answer (score 19):

### 1. Что такое pull request?

#### 1. Определение

**pull request — предложение изменения кода в чужом репозитории.**

Вы делаете форк чужого репозитория (который иногда и сам может быть форком) → производите изменения в своём форке → посредством pull request предлагаете изменения владельцам репозитория, чей форк Вы сделали. На GitHub pull request в публичный репозиторий [**может осуществить любая/ой зарегистрированная/ый участница/участник**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597548/199934).

#### 2. Составляющие pull requests

1. Изменения, которые собираетесь внести в чужой репозиторий,
2. Описание этих изменений.

Рекомендации по грамотному внесению pull requests расписаны [**в ответе ув-мого IonDen**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451731/199934).

#### 3. Разновидности pull requests

Все pull requests можно разделить на следующие категории:

1. Исправление багов, ошибок, конфликтов с другими приложениями,
2. Добавление новых функций, возможностей,
3. Рефакторинг, стилевые правки. Если владелица/владелец репозитория не значительно хуже Вас разбирается в коде репозитория, [**лучше не злоупотреблять**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451731/199934) pull requests данной категории.

#### 4. Дополнительная ссылка

- [**«Pull request'ы на GitHub или Как мне внести изменения в чужой проект» — статья на Хабрахабре**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/125999/).

---

### 2. Как сделать и принять pull request при помощи hub

#### 1. Что такое hub?

[**hub**](https://hub.github.com/) — консольное приложение, упрощающее введение команд git, обёртка для git. Например, чтобы клонировать репозиторий, используя git, мы должны ввести в терминал:

```
git clone https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaSublime.git
```

В hub команда выглядит проще:

```
hub clone Kristinita/SashaSublime
```

Полный список команд hub, и что они упрощают, см. в [**документации hub**](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html).

На момент написания ответа (ноябрь 2016) hub работает [**только с GitHub, но не BitBucket**](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/140) или прочими ресурсами для хранения кода. Для пользователей Windows [**доступна установка**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/hub) через пакетный менеджер Chocolatey — `cinst hub -y`.

#### 2. Зачем использовать hub?

Фиксить мелкие баги и опечатки, а затем сделать pull-request проще через [**веб-интерфейс GitHub**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/5951529). Однако если Ваши изменения довольно значительны, лучше клонировать репозиторий к себе на компьютер по следующим причинам:

- IDE/продвинутые текстовые редакторы предоставляют значительно больше возможностей для работы с кодом в сравнении с редактированием в вебе;
- Могут понадобиться разного рода тесты, недоступные при редактировании в веб-интерфейсе;
- Для многих предпочтительнее работать в терминале.

Итак, вы решили клонировать репозиторий. hub упрощает:

- Клонирование удалённого репозитория; рассмотрено в п. 2.1 данного ответа;
- Форк; достаточно ввести в терминал `hub fork`;
- pull request; после того, как Вы запушили изменения в свой форк, достаточно ввести в терминал `hub pull-request`.

#### 3. Настройка hub перед использованием

1. Создайте [**пользовательскую переменную среды**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb776899(v=vs.85).aspx) `GIT_EDITOR`, — это сделать просто при помощи [**Rapid Environment Editor**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596341/199934), — значением для которой будет путь к исполняемому файлу Вашего редактора, в котором Вам удобно писать pull request message, — описание Вашего pull request, — при необходимости [**добавив аргументы командной строки**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437653/199934). Например, у меня для Sublime Text значение вышло следующим:

> ```
> "D:\Sublime Text 3 x64\sublime_text.exe" -n -w
> ```

[image: GIT_EDITOR]

Если путь к исполняемому файлу содержит пробелы, [**во избежание багов**](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/1397), лучше заключить его в кавычки.

2. При использовании hub в Windows и открытии редактируемых файлов в Sublime Text могут возникнуть проблемы с pull requests от имени администратора. Поскольку это не первая моя проблема, связанная с UAC, а толку от него не вижу, я [**отключил**](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-and-disable-uac-in-windows-10/) у себя контроль учётных записей.
3. Комментарии — текст под сообщением во вкладке `PULLREQ_EDITMSG` — по умолчанию выделяются `#октоторпами#`. Но когда Вы внесёте pull request в чужой репозиторий, то обнаружите, что текст под сообщением отобразится как заголовки, а не комментарии.

[image: Комментарии в hub]

Необходима настройка git. [**Введите в терминал команду**](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/1247#issuecomment-245582549):

```
git config --global core.commentChar %
```

Отныне комментариям во вкладке `PULLREQ_EDITMSG` будут предшествовать символы `%процента%`, после внесения pull request комментариев не будет видно как визуально, так и в исходном коде описания к pull request.

При необходимости резервных копий или синхронизации пользовательской конфигурации файлов git узнать, где хранятся конфигурационные файлы git, [**начиная с версии 2.8**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115116/5951529) можно командой:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

Например, у меня в Windows 10 путь к файлу, где хранится данная настройка для комментариев, оказался следующим:

> ```
> file:C:/Users/SashaChernykh/.gitconfig  core.commentchar=%
> ```

---

Если Ваша проблема отлична от расписанных здесь, и её разрешения не получается найти поисками Google и по репозиторию; попробуйте ещё раз воспроизвести проблему, перед введением команд hub послав в терминал следующую команду:

```
set HUB_VERBOSE=1
```

В терминале появится отладочная информация. Если и по ней не получилось разрешить проблему, создайте багрепорт в [**issue tracker**](https://github.com/github/hub/issues) hub, приложив к сообщению вывод Вашего терминала вместе с отладочной информацией.

#### 4. Пример создания pull request через hub

Сделаем посредством PowerShell и hub pull request в репозиторий **https://github.com/LightAlf/bioRepo1**. Помимо вышеперечисленных команд hub в примере используются также команды git, о предназначении которых можно узнать, например, из [**данного**](https://githowto.com/ru) или [**этого**](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1) ресурсов на русском.

```sh
PS E:\> hub clone LightAlf/bioRepo1
Cloning into 'bioRepo1'...
remote: Counting objects: 16, done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 16
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), done.
PS E:\> cd bioRepo1
PS E:\bioRepo1> Invoke-Item README.MD
# В Вашем редакторе открывается файл README.MD → вносите в него изменения → сохраняете файл.
PS E:\bioRepo1> git add .
PS E:\bioRepo1> git commit -m "Тестирование pull-request посредством hub"
[master 839c146] Тестирование pull-request посредством hub
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
PS E:\bioRepo1> hub fork
Updating Kristinita
From https://github.com/LightAlf/bioRepo1
 * [new branch]      discuss    -> Kristinita/discuss
 * [new branch]      master     -> Kristinita/master
new remote: Kristinita
PS E:\bioRepo1> git checkout -b SashaGoddess
Switched to a new branch 'SashaGoddess'
PS E:\bioRepo1> git push Kristinita SashaGoddess
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 471 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/Kristinita/bioRepo1.git
 * [new branch]      SashaGoddess -> SashaGoddess
PS E:\bioRepo1> hub pull-request
# Откроется вкладка с файлом PULLREQ_EDITMSG, как на картинке ниже → вписываете в него изменения → сохраняете файл → закрываете его.
https://github.com/LightAlf/bioRepo1/pull/2
PS E:\bioRepo1>
```

[image: Pull request в hub]

[**Результат**](https://github.com/LightAlf/bioRepo1/pull/2):

[image: Результат выполнения pull request]

#### 5. Пример принятия pull-request при помощи hub

Если pull request предложен Вам, Вы можете принять его из терминала, воспользовавшись командой hub — [**`hub merge`**](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html). Изменения будут влиты в Ваш локальный репозиторий; чтобы перенести их на удалённый, следует сделать `git push`. Пример, как принять pull-request. если ветка, в которую предложили сделать pull request, является [**веткой по умолчанию**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18032014/5951529).

```sh
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG MINGW32 /e/SashaChocolatey (master)
# Где E:\SashaChocolatey — локальный репозиторий, в связанный с которым удалённый репозиторий был внесён pull-request
$ hub merge https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaChocolatey/pull/1
# Где https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaChocolatey/pull/1 — ссылка на pull-request
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 packages/Karens Replicator/tools/chocolateyinstall.ps1 | 13 +++++--------
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)

SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG MINGW32 /e/SashaChocolatey (master)
$ hub push
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 1.56 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 15 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), completed with 3 local objects.
To https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaChocolatey.git
   79ebe12..5045130  master -> master
```

[**Результат**](https://github.com/LightAlf/bioRepo1/pull/2):

[image: Результат слияния pull request]

В описании коммита по умолчанию будут ссылки на коммит, которым приниматеся pull request, и на сам pull request, а также его заголовок.

[image: Описание коммита]

Пользовательница/пользователь GitHub, у которой/которого Вы приняли pull request, не сразу, но будет указана/указан в числе контрибьюторов Вашего репозитория.

---

### 3. Дополнительная ссылка

- [**Документация и список команд hub**](https://github.com/github/hub/issues).

Comment: Начиная с `2. Как сделать и принять pull request при помощи hub` идёт простыня текста, которая не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. Складывается ощущение, что основной смысл этого текста — в том, чтобы впихнуть побольше скриншотов, на которых запечатлено "SashaGoddess".

Comment: `Разновидности pull requests` – искусственная и бессмысленная классификация. Никто никогда не спрашивает, какого вида ПР нужно открыть.

Comment: `Составляющие pull requests` – это внешние атрибуты, для ПР нужны только две отличающихся ветки. Определение — пальцем в небо. Форк не обязателен для ПР, который может быть внутри одного репозитория. Репозиторий также не обязан быть публичным, ПР возможны в приватных репозиториях. Является ли форком репозиторий, в котором открывается ПР — вообще не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. Репозиторий не обязан быть чужим, вы можете открыть ПР сами себе.

Comment: `Если владелица/владелец репозитория не значительно хуже Вас разбирается в коде репозитория, лучше не злоупотреблять pull requests данной категории` Что, в большинстве ПР владелец репозитория разбирается в его коде значительно хуже, чем контрибьютор? Вы серьёзно так думаете? Обычно всё наоборот, владелец репозитория более компетентен, он проводит ревью и может отклонить ПР. Но обычно никто не ругает за плохой ПР, напротив — дают рекомендации, как улучшить.

Comment: Вы даёте деструктивный совет, рекомендуя читателям не делать свой вклад, если они неопытны. Это остановит их развитие.