# Замена дефолтного редактора кода в git

Tags: git, редактор, git-config

Начал работать с git (а именно c BitBucket) и встроенный редактор (VIM) оказался для меня весьма непонятным в управлении.

Возникло желание заменить его на другой (хоть на встроенный в OS Windows 7 блокнот). Как это сделать?

Comment: Изменить редактор ОС по умолчанию. Какая ОС используется?

Comment: я вроде написал)))виндовс,семка если точнее

Comment: Если что, выход - `:q`

Comment: @Etki, разве редактор ос по умолчанию поможет? Мне казалось msysgit тянет vim с собой

Comment: гит из коробки ничего с собой не тянет.

Comment: @Etki, гит из коробки не тянет, а вот его виндовая реализация по-моему еще как тянет

Comment: @Etki, msysgit тянет.

Comment: А можно просто научиться сохранять и выходить из Vim. Поверьте, он полезный. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437417/181472

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 1. Уровни настройки.

Редактор, который использует Git, выбирается из следующего списка, именно в этом порядке (из `man git-commit`):

1. Значение переменной окружения `GIT_EDITOR`
2. Значение в конфигурации Git `core.editor`. Используется обычный для Git приоритет настроек:

   1. `--local` — для данного проекта.
   2. `--global` — для данного пользователя. Логично настраивать редактор именно на этом уровне.
   3. `--system` — для этой рабочей машины (в рамках ОС).
3. Значение переменной окружения `VISUAL`
4. Значение переменной окружения `EDITOR` ([зачем столько переменных?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4859/124726))
5. Если все эти варианты не установлены, то использует Vi/Vim.

### 2. Зачем `-w`?

Зачем в большинстве приведенных команд параметр `-w` (`--wait`)? Git открывает редактор и ждет возврата [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), чтобы продолжить работу на основе данных в файле. Если этого параметра нет, Git будет продолжать работу сразу и не дождется, когда вы отредактируете и сохраните файл.

из `atom -h`:

```
-w, --wait   Wait for window to be closed before returning.
```

### 3. Настройка через изменение `core.editor`.

Не требует прямого редактирования файлов и обладает гибкостью в уровнях настройки. Минус в том, что остальные приложения продолжат использовать редактор по умолчанию.

В общем виде настройка конфигурации выглядит так:

```
git config --global core.editor "editor --parameters"
```

#### 3.1 Linux, OS X

Многие редакторы (Atom, TextWrangler и другие) не включают поддержку командной строки при установке. Их необходимо включить отдельно, найдя в меню команду <kbd>Install Shell Commands</kbd>.

Эти строки можно сразу копировать и выполнять в терминале:

[Atom](https://atom.io/):

```
git config --global core.editor "atom -w"
```

[Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (`-w` по умолчанию):

```
git config --global core.editor "emacs"
```

[Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/2)

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

[Textmate](http://macromates.com/)

```
git config --global core.editor "mate -w"
```

[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)

```
git config --global core.editor "edit -w"
```

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/) (`-w` по умолчанию):

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

#### 3.2 Windows

Вариант 1: добавить редактор [в переменную PATH](http://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml) и использовать строки как для *nix.

Некоторые редакторы при установке сами прописывают себя в PATH.

Вариант 2: не меняя переменную PATH, напрямую указать путь к исполняемому файлу. Обратите внимание на вложенность кавычек <s>и на то, как лаконично выглядит параметр `--wait` под Windows</s>.

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), на 32-битной ОС ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431003/2790048)):

```
git config --global core.editor \
"'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Notepad++, на 64-битной ОС:

```
git config --global core.editor \
"'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Comment: вы как всегда на высоте=)спасибо

Comment: @DarkVss: спасибо за высокую оценку. Осталось про настройку `$EDITOR` и `$VISUAL` написать.

Answer (score 5):

В гите есть настройка для редактора, можно сделать например так

```
git config --global core.editor youreditor
```

Переменная `youreditor`  должна быть [прописана в `PATH`](http://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml). Когда Вы набираете в виндовой консоли `youreditor`, то консоль лезет в `PATH` и смотрит, какой файл соответствует собственно `youreditor`.

Однако менять его стоит на что-то продвинутое, с обычным блокнотом Вы гарантированно получите немало проблем, в частности с окончаниями строк.

Comment: я пытаюсь хоть на что-то более функциональное поменять. такой вариант я сразу испробовал.итог-в конфиге поменялось,а на деле нет....

Comment: @DarkVss функциональнее vim сложнее что-то придумать. просто нужно научиться его готовить

Comment: @DarkVss, Вы прописали путь к вашему более функциональному редактору в переменных окружения?

Comment: @MakarovAV благодарю)

Answer (score 0):

Очень удобный редактор git средах от JetBrains (PHPStorm, WebStorm, RubyMine, IDEA)

Алгоритм добавления git репозитория:

1. VCS -> Enable VCI
2. `git add ./`
3. Создаем на BitBucket новый репозиторий
4. Прописываем в настройках терминала phpstom `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`  - в случае windows, 
    `/bin/bash` - в случае linux
5. Пишем в консоли

   ```
   git remote add origin https://ASDAlexey@bitbucket.org/ASDAlexey/angular-multi-select.git
   ```

Comment: Я не понял, а причем тут добавление репозитория? Зачем при этом добавлять файлы и не коммитить их?

Comment: Конечно в JetBrains (PHPStorm, WebStorm, RubyMine, IDEA) можно коммитит и пушить. Я просто описал алгоритм подключения редактора к git bitbucket.org аналогично подключается и к github
Внутри JetBrains хороший визуальный интерфейн git, но также паралльно с ним можно пользоваться обычным терминолом, который тоже встроен в JetBrains.

Comment: да, я тоже всегда пользуюсь встроенной консолью в IDEA (впрочем, она вроде как просто "прокси" для zsh ). Вы в принципе дельный ответ написали, только он не на этот вопрос. Вот мне интересно, можно ли чтобы после команды `git commit` (без параметра `-m"..."`) у меня редактирование сообщения открывалось в IDEA. Знаете, как такое настроить?

Comment: и, кстати, если дефолтный редактор не заменить, то даже из консоли в IDEA после команды `git commit ` или `git rebase -i <revision>` откроется Vim.