# Как создать репозиторий на GitHub через командную строку?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

В папке с проектом создаю локальный репозиторий (`git init`), выполняю весь необходимый минимум (`git add .`, `git commit -m "Описание коммита"`), и пробую выложить его в свой аккаунт на GitHub:

```
$ git remote add git_prj https://github.com/Gooddjamp/git_prj.git
$ git push -u git_prj master
```

А возвращается ошибка:

> remote: Repository not found.
>   fatal: repository 'https: // github.com / Gooddjamp/git_prj.git/' not found

Помогите решить проблему, как выложить свой проект на GitHub.

Comment: Создай там, склонируй себе в папку, добавить новый файл, закомить и отправь в гитхаб

Comment: Так все работает: создал репозиторий в акаунте на github.com, клонировал себе на пк, добавил файлы проэкта, закомитил, отправил на github, все ок... НО хотелось бы создать репозиторий удаленно, перенести свой локальный репозиторий на github, а не получаеться (((

Comment: @Gooddjamp: в таком случае измените формулировку вопроса, так как Вашего НО там нет.

Comment: edem, Вы правы, формулировка была не точна. Спасибо

Comment: [Тут](http://maxsite.org/page/how-to-put-your-project-on-github-com)  пишут, так :`...$ git remote add origin https://github.com/USER/demo.git ...$
git push -u origin master` Похоже, разница в `origin`

Comment: В даном случаи prj (вместо origun) - это короткое имя url, которое можно использовать дальше вместо url

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2423777/5000805

Answer (score 26):

### Linux / OS X

Создаем удаленный репозиторий, указывая имя учетной записи.

```
curl -u 'USER_NAME' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d'{"name":"demo"}'
```

Вводим пароль от учетной записи:

> Enter host password for user 'USER_NAME':

Репозиторий `demo` создан.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь выгружаем проект.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/USER_NAME/demo.git
git push -u origin master
```

---

### Windows

#### Вариант 1:

Устанавливаем  утилиту [cURL](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/) и перезагружаемся. Дальше последовательность идентична Linux.

#### Вариант 2 (Спасибо [@PinkTux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194908/pinktux)):

Cкачиваем архив [wget](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tumagcc/files/), разархивируем в любое место на диске и прописываем путь в переменной  `PATH`.
Открываем командную строку и пишем следующее:

```
wget https://api.github.com/user/repos --user=%USER_NAME --password=%PASSWORD --auth-no-challenge --post-data="{\"name\":\"demo\"}"
```

Обратите внимание на экранирование кавычек *(обратный слэш перед кавычкой)* в `--post-data`.
Не смотря на отсутствие необходимости перезагрузки, все же способ имеет и недостаток - необходимо **явно в строке указывать пароль**.

---

Таким способом можно создавать репозитории с различными параметрами.Вот туд приведен полный [перечень параметров](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create).
Например для создания приватного репозитория *(если у вас есть конечно такая привилегия*) нужно подставить в первую строку после `-d`:

```
'{"name":"demo", "private":"true"}'
```

---

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-ssh/10325316#10325316)

Comment: Плюс за true unix way создания репозитория ))

Comment: А почему `.../demo.git` в `git remote ...`, если в `curl ...` дали имя  `{"name":"demo"}` (т.е. без .git)? По моему (пока еще начальному) опыту на github создается репозиторий в точности с указанным  именем. Вообще, надежней перед `git remote ...` зайти на github в только что созданный  проект и скопировать URL

Comment: @avp, вы совершенно правы и именно так я и поступил – взял код, предлагаемый GitHub'ом. Ваш вопрос меня заинтересовал, и я [нашел](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068576/why-do-some-repository-urls-end-in-git-while-others-dont) на него ответ на EngSO. Если я правильно понял `.git` в url используется для обращения к чистым репозиториям. Попробовал обратится без `.git`– коммит улетел на удаленный репозиторий . Спасибо за Ваш комментарий.

Comment: *"Устанавливаем утилиту cURL и перезагружаемся"* -- а перезагружаться зачем? Впрочем, можно и так, уж `wget` никакой перезагрузки не потребует, только один его exe-шник положить в `PATH` и всё: `wget.exe -O NUL --auth-no-challenge --user=USER --password=PASSWORD "https://api.github.com/user/repos" --post-data='{"name":"demo"}'` (насчёт NUL не уверен, не помню как там в windows "в никуда" отправить, чтобы он HTTP-ответ в файле не сохранял)

Comment: @PinkTux о, спасибо спасибо. попозже проверю и добавлю.

Comment: @avp вот как раз гитхаб эти `.git` и подставляет в своих примерах

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Создание удалённого репозитория при помощи hub

[**hub**](https://hub.github.com/) — консольное приложение, упрощающее введение команд git и позволяющее производить некоторые недоступные для git действия в удалённых репозиториях из терминала. Так, при помощи hub возможно создание нового GitHub репозитория без обращений к веб-интерфейсу, для этого используется команда

> hub create

Необязательные параметры команды:

- `-d` — описание репозитория, на сайте GitHub располагается под именами пользователя и репозитория;
- `-h` — ссылка на сайт, соответствующий репозиторию, в веб-интерфейсе GitHub находится рядом с описанием;
- `-p` — сделать репозиторий приватным; параметр доступен [**только если у Вас платный GitHub аккаунт**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600240/5951529).

[image: Описание и ссылка]

---

---

### 2. Демонстрация

Создаём, используя Git Bash, репозиторий с именем `KristinitaTest.github.io` в Windows.

```bash
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG MINGW32 /e
$ mkdir KristinitaTest.github.io
# Имя папки станет и именем Вашего удалённого репозитория.
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG MINGW32 /e
$ cd KristinitaTest.github.io

SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG MINGW32 /e/KristinitaTest.github.io
$ touch README.MD

SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG MINGW32 /e/KristinitaTest.github.io
$ start README.MD
# Пишем «Repository for test GitHub features and demonstrations.» в файл README.MD.
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG MINGW32 /e/KristinitaTest.github.io
$ hub init
Initialized empty Git repository in E:/KristinitaTest.github.io/.git/

SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG MINGW32 /e/KristinitaTest.github.io (master)
$ hub add . && git commit -m "Repository for Sasha tests"
[master (root-commit) b56f811] Repository for Sasha tests
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README.MD

SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG MINGW32 /e/KristinitaTest.github.io (master)
$ hub create -d "Create test repository" -h "Kristinita.ru"
Updating origin
created repository: Kristinita/KristinitaTest.github.io
# Протокол «http://» будет добавлен автоматически в имя сайта.
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG MINGW32 /e/KristinitaTest.github.io (master)
$ hub push -u origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 296 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaTest.github.io.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Новый репозиторий успешно создан.

[image: Hub create]

---

---

### 3. Примечания

1. В ответе подразумевается, что Вы уже [**связаны с аккаунтом на GitHub**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6565357/5951529), и Вам не придётся при каждом push вводить логин/пароль.
2. Лично протестировано только на Windows 10, но так как hub — кроссплатформенная утилита, решение должно работать и в других операционных системах.

---

---

### 4. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**документация hub**](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html),
- [**другие примеры использования hub**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598162/199934).

Comment: Саша, прошу Вас прочитать мой комментарий к этому ответу: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608812/

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно сначала создать репозиторий на гитхабе, чтобы потом в него что-то можно было пушить. Проще всего все-таки сделать это через веб-интерфейс.

Только, если вам предложат выбрать для репозитория лицензию, файл gitignore и пр. - отказывайтесь, вам нужен именно пустой репозиторий на гитхабе, чтобы можно было запушить в него ваш проект без конфликтов.

(Впрочем, конфликты тут не страшны - можно же и `push -f` сделать)

---

PS когда вы копируете ваши файлы на флешку (много файлов), вы перед этим обычно создаете пустую папку, куда будете копировать. Репозиторий - это контейнер для коммитов, точно так же как папка - контейнер для файлов. Пуш репозитория на гитхаб - это просто копирование ваших коммитов. Так почему же вы решили, что можно обойтись без создания пустого репозитория на гитхабе?

Answer (score 1):

Существует официальный интерфейс командной строки для гитхаба — [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/)

[Пример](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create) использования:

```
gh repo create [<name>] [flags]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Через консоль заходите в папку проекта `cd C:\...`
2. Создаете репозиторий на github, копируете код(скрин приложил) и вставляете в командную строку.
   [image: Скрин]
   `git remote add origin https://github.com/Skin-nikS/-.git`

   `git branch -M master`

   `git push -u origin master`