# Если у меня public repository, то кто может редактировать проект?

Tags: github

Если у меня public repository, то кто может редактировать мой проект?

Comment: Если репозиторий принадлежит персональному аккаунту (не аккаунту организации) - то только вы и, в исключительных случаях, администрация.

Comment: Но, любой встречный-поперечный сможет ваш проект форкнуть и отредактировать у себя.

Comment: @Etki поправка - при настройках по умолчанию

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Кто может редактировать Ваш публичный репозиторий?

- Вы,
- Пользовательницы/пользователи GitHub, [**которым Вы в настройках предоставили доступ**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8015579/5951529) к редактированию репозитория,
- В исключительных случаях сотрудницы/сотрудники GitHub.

---

---

### 2. Pull-request

Однако любая/любой пользовательница/пользователь GitHub может предложить [**pull-request**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/134183/199934). Она/он делает изменения в форке Вашего репозитория (форки другие пользовательницы/пользователи могут править, как им заблагорассудится) и предлагает Вам влить их в свой репозиторий. Необходимо, чтобы Вы приняли эти изменения; без Вашего согласия никто помимо вышеперечисленных трёх групп править Ваш репозиторий не может.

---

---

### 3. Дополнительная ссылка

- [**«Editing files in another user's repository» на сайте GitHub.**](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-another-user-s-repository/)

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае слово public говорит о том, что весь код который вы отправите на репозиторий будет **доступен всем желающим для просмотра** в открытом доступе, **редактировать можете только вы**. В случае если это **командный проект редактировать сможет вся команда**, при этом все предыдущие версии и изменения сохраняются. Если вам нечего скрывать, то в этом нет ничего страшного, а возможно даже ваш код кому то поможет. Услуги закрытого репозитория, гитхаб предоставляет за отдельную плату.

Comment: В ответе нет ничего, что отвечало бы на вопрос **кто может редактировать проект**? Если исправите ответ, сниму минус. Спасибо.

Comment: А мне кажется, этот ответ вполне отвечает на вопрос. Да, "редактировать можете только вы" или команда. Я бы плюсанул.