# Как сделать рваные края в ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

Нужно сделать рваные края на картинке, [**пример есть тут**](http://infonion.ru/vladislav/uroki-fotoshop/urok-4-effekt-rvanyx-kraev-v-fotoshope-ocherednaya-stupenka-dlya-chajnika). Но сделать надо в ImageMagick и независимо от того, какого размера изображение. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: У ImageMagick есть [**скрипт**](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bordereffects/index.php) для Вашей цели, однако у меня [**возникли проблемы с его использованием**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42038802/5951529). Скрипты написаны для Linux/macOS; если у Вас не Windows, думаю, полегче будет с ними. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных то что надо переносите в ответ

Comment: Пожалуйста, разместите пример результата **непосредственно в вопросе**. Ссылка не годится.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### 1. bordereffects

[image: border] Эффект, который понадобился ув-му автору вопроса, например, в Greenshot называется Torn edge. Его можно добиться и при помощи нативных команд ImageMagick, см. пример [**на официальном сайте**](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#torn) (к сожалению, он там только один).

Однако писать придётся многовато. На мой взгляд, намного проще использовать скрипт для ImageMagick, называемый [**bordereffects**](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bordereffects/index.php). Да, на сайте с `bordereffects` присутствует огромное количество бесплатных скриптов — [**Fred's ImageMagick Scripts**](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/) — упрощающих работу с ImageMagick.

У пользователей Windows могут возникнуть проблемы с использованием скриптов, поскольку все они написаны под Linux/macOS. Как у меня получилось запустить `bordereffects`, см. в разделе 3.

---

### 2. Демонстрация

#### 1. Ограничения в демонстрационных примерах

- демонстрируется простой запуск команд в Cygwin терминале,
- в примерах преобразование происходит только для одного изображения.

#### 2. Torn edge

***Исходный файл `SashaQueen.jpg`:***

[image: Исходный файл]

***Эффект Torn edge в файле `SashaMagic.jpg`:***

> ```
> bordereffects -s 25 -d 1 -c 10 -g 1 -p 1 SashaQueen.jpg SashaMagic.jpg
> ```

[image: Torn Edge]

Оптимальные значения опций различны в зависимости от размеров изображений.

#### 3. Примеры опций bordereffects

Значения опций, кроме той, о которой идёт речь, остаются такими же, как в примере с Torn edge.

1. `-d` — `density`. При больших значениях (в примере `-d 50`) изображения будут выглядеть так:

[image: Density]

2. `-g` — `granularity`. При больших значениях (в примере `-g 50`) изображения будут выглядеть так:

[image: Granularity]

3. `-c` — `curviness`. При небольших значениях (в примере `-с 1`) изображения будут выглядеть так:

[image: Curviness]

Подробные описания команд и больше примеров смотрите на [**сайте bordereffects**](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bordereffects/index.php).

---

### 3. Запуск Fred's ImageMagick Scripts в Windows

[image: Fred] В Cygwin на примере `bordereffects`. Для остальных скриптов действия примерно те же.

#### 1. Программно-аппаратное окружение

Протестировано лично на

- Windows 10 64-bit Enterprise LTSB EN,
- ImageMagick 7.0.4-3 Q16 x64 2017-01-07,
- Cygwin 2.6.1,
- cyg-get 1.2.1.

Для запуска в 64-битных Windows можно использовать и [**Bash для Windows**](https://www.opennet.ru/tips/2963_ubuntu_windows_bash_wsl.shtml), однако в Windows LTSB на момент написания данного сообщения [**Bash не поддерживается**](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1281).

#### 2. Установка и настройка

Устанавливаем [**Cygwin**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Cygwin) и [**cyg-get**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get). Скачиваем `bordereffects` [**с официального сайта**](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bordereffects/index.php) в папку, которая есть в [**пользовательской переменной PATH**](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml) или же добавляем папку с `bordereffects` в пользовательскую переменную PATH — это удобно делать через [**Rapid Environment Editor**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596341/199934).

Открываем файл `bordereffects` в любом продвинутом текстовом редакторе → делаем, включив поиск/замену регулярными выражениями замену `\bconvert\b` — `magick`, поскольку в Windows [**есть нативная команда convert**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38319795/5951529), → делаем замену `\bidentify\b` — `magick identify` → сохраняем файл.

#### 3. Работа в Cygwin

Открываем терминал Cygwin — для запуска команд Cygwin нужен специализированный терминал, обычной [**консолью Windows**](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160529035311/http://www.conemu.ru/ru/Delusions.html#delusion-2) не обойтись; я запускаю его ярлыком Cygwin64 Terminal из [**Wox**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/wox). В терминале Cygwin [**перемещаемся**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15673422/5951529) в папку, где лежат изображения, которые необходимо преобразовать, → проверяем, что всё работает, запуском команды `bordereffects`, например, `bordereffects SashaQueen.jpg SashaMagic.jpg`.

Если в консоли появляются сообщения, что какая-то команда из скрипта `bordereffects` не запускается, в предпочтительном для Вас терминале для Windows (уже не в терминале Cygwin) набираем команду `cyg-get`. Синтаксис: `cyg-get firstpackage secondpackage thirdpackage`. Например, после запуска bordereffects выяснилось, что у меня отсутствовала [**утилита `bc`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) → установил её командой `cyg-get bc`.

> При установке `bc` вручную с [**сайта GnuWin**](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bc.htm) у меня возникали баги, связанные с этим интерпретатором, поэтому рекомендовал бы устанавливать недостающие команды через пакетный менеджер `cyg-get`.