# Не запускается javac

Tags: java, компиляция, javac

Javac отказывается компилировать. Что делать? Пробовал и javac и javac.exe. П.с. открывал PowerShell в нужной папке с зажатым шифтом и JDK установлен.

Полный текст в компиляторе:

> PS C:\Users\User-01\Desktop\JProjects\Jcodes> javac Подсчет количества
>   слов.java javac : Имя "javac" не распознано как имя командлета,
>   функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте
>   правильность написания имени, а также наличие и п равильность пути,
>   после чего повторите попытку. строка:1 знак:1
>   + javac Подсчет количества слов.java
>   + ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (javac:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

.

> PS C:\Users\User-01\Desktop\JProjects\Jcodes> javac.exe Подсчет
>   количества слов.java javac.exe : Имя "javac.exe" не распознано как имя
>   командлета, функции, файла сцена рия или выполняемой программы.
>   Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также нал ичие и
>   правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку. строка:1 знак:1
>   + javac.exe Подсчет количества слов.java
>   + ~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (javac.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Вы в переменные среды путь до bin директории jdk закинули?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно настроить системные переменные.

[Как задать или настроить системную переменную PATH?](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml)

[Системные переменные CLASSPATH и JAVA_HOME в Windows 7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44587/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-windows-7)

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я их указал, но ничего не изменилось(

Comment: Запускать надо не в powershell, а в cmd и ещё имя файла с пробелами необходимо взять в кавычки, например: `javac.exe "Подсчет количества слов.java"`